# Export database to CSV with columns PHP

Tags: php, csv

Here my php script to export database info to CSV file.

I dont arrive to put any structure to correctly tidy my infos in my CSV file.

For example, put all names in a name column, all emails in an email column... etc

```
include_once('conf.php');
include_once('BDD.php');

header('charset=UTF-8');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");


$bdd = new BDD($conf['bddhost'], $conf['bddport'], $conf['bddname'], $conf['bdduser'], $conf['bddpass']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
$qry = $bdd->prepare($sql);

// Execute the statement
$qry->execute();

$data = fopen('/tmp/db_user_export_".time().".csv', 'w');


while ($row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    // Export every row to a file
    fputcsv($data, $row);
    echo ''.$row['prenom'].' '
                .$row['nom'].' '
                .$row['email'].' '
                .$row['cp'].' '
                .$row['information'].'  
                ';
}
fclose($data);
```

Comment: What is your question?  I realize there's a language barrier, but it's difficult to understand what you're asking or how your code doesn't work.

Comment: `CSV - "comma separated values"`...where's your commas? Where's your quotes? WHat is the question?

Comment: you may want to activate errors (`error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`) and check the output of `fputcsv` which should return the length of the string written. Maybe try to remove `header()`s functions to help debugging. Maybe it's a write permission on /tmp

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `echo` as you are creating the file with `fputcsv`

```
while ($row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    // Export every row to a file
    fputcsv($data, $row);
}

// reset the file pointer to the beginning of the file
rewind($data);

// dump the csv file and stop the script
fpassthru($data);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax errors:

```
$data = fopen('/tmp/db_user_export_".time().".csv', 'w');
              ^--                  ^--      ^--  ^---
```

You're mixing string quoting styles, so your filename is literally going to contain the characters `"`, `.`, `t`, etc... in it.

Try

```
$data = fopen('/tmp/db_user_export_' .time() .'.csv', 'w');
                                   ^----------^---
```

instead. Note the change from `"` -> `'`.